# WRT page doesn't change even if i changed the code completly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nokia-wrt

Whatever i changed in the page in visual studio it is showing same page during it is working or restarting until i clean the project manually.

What should i do to show changes without cleaning the project?

`wrt_preview_main.html` file isn't reloading automatically. It always contains old code of my index.html.

Answer (score 0):

It its because browser cache check:
http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?168964-Widget-Cache

Just go to menu>web>options>clear privacy data>cache (on N97)